# How to stop visual studio from creating tests database after and on 3001st test

Tags: c#, visual-studio, testing

I ran into a strange thing today, I was writing tests in C# in Visual Studio and it just started creating a test database in the `TestResults` folder after hitting my 3001st test. It saves test names, runner information and so on.

**Database Structure**

[image: Here's a database structure.]

Is there a way to disable Visual Studio from creating a test database in the `TestResults` folder? Because that thing is heavy...